# php curl nginx proxy forward load time

Tags: php, curl, nginx, proxy

I'm using php curl with nginx as a proxy. here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

I put this simple script on my production server and run in against some url.

I tested it with the following command:

```
time wget -pq --no-cache --delete-after www.growingcraft.com
```

The load time of the url through the proxy is about 3.1 seconds, while load time of the same code with out the proxy (i.e. comment out the 'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);' line) takes about 1.1 seconds.

The servers are hosted by rackspace, and I got the same result when using maximum  size (i.e. CPU   8 vCPUs, RAM    30 GB,System Disk   1.2 TB,Network  1.2 Gb / s, Disk I/O    Good), and minimum size

There is nothing else running/using the proxy server.

My questions are:

1. is a 2 seconds delay is normal for a forward proxy? or is it faster/slower than normal
2. Is there anything I can do to reduce this delay? i.e. change srv, change nginx, etc

10x

Answer (score 1):

The proxy server will always add a bit of delay 2.2 secound is not to bad, this is done due to the fact that you are using a "second" server to request content from the first server and then redirect them to the user. This may be able to be reduced if you can make your code more lightweight or make the server more powerfull but is not bad at all at the moment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server